# select2 search dropdown top offset incorrect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Bit of an odd issue with a `select2` multiple field where on subsequent searches, the dropdown search message displays incorrectly. See below:

[image: The problem]

The marked blue area is the `select2` field and the marked red area is where the dropdown message is displaying. Note that when the search is done, the results display in the right position, but for some reason the message displays higher up than it should.

Params on init:

```
$budgetAdmins.select2({
        placeholder: 'Type a person\’s name...',
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        createSearchChoicePosition: 'bottom',
        dropdownParent: $budgetAdmins.closest('.budget-field'),
        type: 'POST',
        ajax: {
            url: theme.ajax_url,
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250
            data: ...
       }
});
```

Other details on the implementation:

- This bug only happens when the browser viewport height is small enough to force the message and subsequent list to the top (usually displays fine at the bottom).
- Once the list gets displayed, it correctly fits to the top of field and only the message to enter 3 or more characters and AJAX loading message gets pushed so far up.
- I've only included `createSearchChoicePosition` and `dropdownParent` in an attempt to solve this issue. It has had no effect.
- The first focus of the search box displays the message fine, flush against the top of the field. This issue only happens on the second focus after selecting a value. It then works on the next focus and then breaks again on the following focus. Also, when the display is broken, it's fixed by scrolling the page.
- Using `select2` version 4.0.5.

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a hack fix:

```
$budgetAdmins.on('select2:open', e => {
    var timer = setTimeout(() => {
        jQuery('html, body').trigger('scroll');
    }, 1);
});
```

I've tried it without the `setTimeout` but it had no effect.